# Reading/writing files in Python

Tags: python, file, read-write

I am trying to create a new text file of stock symbols in the russell 2k from one that looks like this:

[image]

All I want is the ticker symbol at the end of each line. So I have the following code:

```
with open("russ.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.split()
        line = line[-1]
        if line == "Ticker": continue
        print line
        with open("output.txt", "w") as fh:
            fh.seek(0,2)
            print line
            fh.write(line)
```

All I end up with in the `output.txt` file is one line with the very last ticker in the list instead of all the tickers. I thought using `fh.seek(0,2)` would create a new line at the end each time through.  What am I doing wrong? Also, in reality I don't need to create another doc, I could just edit the current one but I couldn't figure that out either so if you could show me how to just write to the same file that also is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: So Basically, you trying to read *Ticker* symbol from `russ.txt` file, which is at the end of each line and write it to `output.txt` file?

Comment: Or even *overwriting* these *Ticker` symbols over `russ.txt` content?

Comment: You can't just overwrite a file as you read it. To do that effectively, you'd read the whole file into memory, delete it, then recreate it with its new content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filemode `"w"` creates a new empty file in each step. Either use mode `"a"` for append, or move the file opening outside the loop.

```
with open("russ.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.split()
        line = line[-1]
        if line == "Ticker": continue
        print line
        with open("output.txt", "a") as fh:
            fh.write(line + "\n")
```

or better, open the file only once:

```
with open("russ.txt", "r") as f, open("output.txt", "w") as fh:
    for line in f:
        symbol = line.split()[-1]
        if symbol != "Ticker":
            print symbol
            fh.write(symbol + "\n")
```

Comment: can you explain why `fh.seek(0,2)
            print line
            fh.write(line)` was not working and why your second method does?

Comment: @futevolei: each time, you open the file with `"w"`, all contents is lost. So, seeking to the end has no effect at all.

Comment: I realized this morning that it is still writing "Tickers" to the file, do you know why?

Comment: @futevolei: is there a 's' missing?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that wrong.  "Ticker" is still being written.

Answer (score 1):

I believe using [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/fileinput.html?highlight=fileinput#fileinput.input) will be also handy in your case:

```
import fileinput
import sys


for line in fileinput.input("russ.txt", inplace=1):
    sys.stdout.write(line.split(' ')[-1])
```

`fileinput.input` will change original file.

Comment: Yes this works.  I had to add `"if line.split()[-1] == "Ticker": continue` before the final line to clean up one thing but otherwise this is great.  Thank you!

Comment: Ok @futevolei .. It was only generic and you had to adopt to your needs, Consider accepting the answer if you feel it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file into a list and then use the `.split()` method to split it along the spaces. Since the ticekr is the last element of the list. You can get it via negative indexing.

```
f = [line.strip() for line in open('so.txt')]
for i in f:
    print i.split(' ')[-1]
```

Input file:

```
STARK INDUSTRIES ST
STARK INDUSTRIES ST
STARK INDUSTRIES ST
STARK INDUSTRIES ST
STARK INDUSTRIES ST
```

Output:

```
ST
ST
ST
ST
ST
```

Comment: `split()` with no arguments does whitespace by default

Comment: I ran into an `list index out of range` error when no using the `' '` in the parenthesis

Comment: Hmm. You might have needed to `trim().rstrip()` the line instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the file each time you open it. Move the `with` line outside of the `for` block, and seek to the end before writing (or open in append mode).

Comment: I tried that and it didnt seem to work.  fh.seek(0,2) is correct to have each new line go at the end of the file right?