# How do I write the output of one function to a file?

Tags: python, function, file-writing

The function I want to the write the output of is:

```
def display_pokemon(pokemon_list):
    pokemon_count = 0
    for x in pokemon_list:
        pokemon_count += 1
        # Requirement 5
        print("Name of Pokemon #{}: ".format(pokemon_count), x.get_name())
        print("Ability of Pokemon #{}: ".format(pokemon_count), x.get_ability())
```

The list being passed through display_pokemon is populated by the user previously as display_pokemon then prints something like:

> Name of Pokemon #1: Pikachu

> Ability of Pokemon #1: Thunderbolt

And that output is what I want to collect from this function to write to a file.

Essentially this is how I want my main() to look:

```
def main():
    pokemon_list = add_pokemon()
    display_pokemon(pokemon_list)
    file_name = input("\nEnter the name of the file?: ")
    save_data(file_name)
    display_data(file_name)
```

Comment: You should reorgnize your code. Separate it into functions that format data and functions that write data. Then you can call the formatting function and write its result to the file.

Comment: Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571390/reading-writing-files-in-python I think it has what you need.

Comment: The reason you're having difficulty is that this isn't "output" from the function, it's just something that your function causes to be displayed using `print`. To get information back from a function, you should use `return`.

Answer (score 2):

The first change that you would make is to your `display_pokemon`. Instead of printing this string, you can add it to an array.

```
def display_pokemon(pokemon_list):
    output = []
    pokemon_count = 0
    for x in pokemon_list:
        pokemon_count += 1
        # Requirement 5
        print("Name of Pokemon #{}: ".format(pokemon_count), x.get_name())
        print("Ability of Pokemon #{}: ".format(pokemon_count), x.get_ability())
        # Writing to output
        output.append(f"Name of Pokemon #{pokemon_count}: {x.get_name()}")
        output.append(f"Ability of Pokemon #{pokemon_count}: {x.get_ability()}")
    return output
```

Then, just write to a file destination:

```
def main():
    pokemon_list = add_pokemon()
    to_write = display_pokemon(pokemon_list)

    file_name = r"some\file.txt"
    file = open(file_name, "w+")
    for i in to_write:
        file.write(i)
        file.write("\n")
  
    file.close()
```

**EDIT:** if you would like to have the writing in a `save_file()`  function, then the code for main would be changed to:

```
def main() :
    pokemon_list = add_pokemon() 
    to_write = display_pokemon(pokemon_list)
    file_name = r"some/file.py"

    def save_file(file_name, to_write):
        file = open(file_name, "w+")
        for i in to_write:
            file.write(i)
            file.write("\n")
  
        file.close() 

    save_file(file_name, to_write)
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I need the "writing" to be contained within the function of save_data in main, which is why I'm stuck at this wall trying to collect the printed results of display_pokemon and pass it through to writing. So I can't use your array solution, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

So what you want to do is:

```
def display_pokemon(pokemon_list):
    file_name = input('"\nEnter the name of the file?: "')
    with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
        pokemon_count = 0
        for x in pokemon_list:
            pokemon_count += 1
            # Requirement 5
            pokemon_name = "Name of Pokemon #{}: ".format(pokemon_count) + x.get_name()
            print(pokemon_name)
            file.write(pokemon_name + '\n')
            pokemon_ability = "Ability of Pokemon #{}: ".format(pokemon_count) + x.get_ability()
            print(pokemon_ability)
            file.write(pokemon_ability)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function currently uses `sys.stdout` as the hard-coded destination file for the calls to `print`. Make the file to use an argument instead; you can still use `sys.stdout` as the *default*.

```
def display_pokemon(pokemon_list, out=sys.stdout):
    for count, x in enumerate(pokemon_list, start=1):
        # Requirement 5
        print("Name of Pokemon #{}: ".format(count), x.get_name(), file=out)
        print("Ability of Pokemon #{}: ".format(count), x.get_ability(), file=out)
```

Now you can call the function as before to write to standard output, or pass a different file:

```
def main():
    pokemon_list = add_pokemon()
    with open(r'some\file.txt', 'w') as fh:
        display_pokemon(pokemon_list, out=fh)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `redirect_stdout` context manager from `contextlib` to redirect the stdout temporarily
For example, the following code would make the output of the function call `display_pokemon()` to a file named `file_name`

```
with open(file_name, 'w') as out, contextlib.redirect_stdout(out):
    display_pokemon(pokemon_list)
```