# Editing text files in python

Tags: python-3.x, file

I'm trying to edit text files in real time, like this text box here, you can write and edit any word you want and then save it to the file, think nano for linux. Anyone know a way of doing this?

I have no idea how to start so I haven't tried anything.
Also something simple please doesn't need to be crazy efficient.

The reading and current writing part of the script look like this:

```
f = open('./PYOS/startMessage.txt', 'r')
start_message = f.read()
print(start_message)
f.close()
while True:
    user_input = str(input('P:\> '))
    command = user_input.lower()
    if command == 'read':
        filename = input('Filename: ')
        try:
            file = open(filename, 'r')
            cont = file.read(filename)
            print('File contents: ', cont)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print('File not found please try again')
    elif command == 'write':
        filename = input('Filename: ')
        try:
            file = open(filename, 'w')
            write = input('Write in file: ')
            cont = file.read(filename)
            print('You wrote: ', cont)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print('File not found please try again')
```

Comment: Do you want to start with how to display an editable textbox perhaps via tkinter or do you want to start by reading altering and writing text to a file perhaps with `open()`?

Comment: I want to display a wall of text with open().

Comment: check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571390/reading-writing-files-in-python

Comment: @JonSG that’s only for appending